# Write a Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem to write a Java regular expression, here are the requirements of matching strings:

- `' or abc` : match
- `X' or abc` : match
- `Good X' or abc` : match
- `Good 'X' or abc` : not match

I am using java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher. match means java.util.regex.Matcher.matches() returns true.

Here is the regular expression I have written: `".*((((?<!\\')[^\\s\\']+))[\\'\\s]+(or|and)).*"`. But it doesn't work.

For some requirements in my application, I **have to use ".*"** at the beginning and the end of the regular expression.

I am new to regex, can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the rule for match/not match with regular words?

Comment: Have you tried `^[^']*'[^']*$`? If you are using the `String#matches` method, you can remove the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the regex

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ commes in handy if you have to debug regular expresions

Comment: Can you clarify a bit when it should match and when it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use .* at the beginning of the expression, then this one works:

```
".*(?=(?<!Good 'X)' or abc$).*"
```

The trick is that it looks ahead using "(?=" expressions that end with "' or abc", but without "Good 'X" in front of it - using negative lookbehind "(?< !".

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. This is a good solution. But I prefer a more general solution, like not using "Good 'X" in the regex.

Comment: Which parts of the strings are significant? If you want a generic expression, you need to describe patterns that should (not) be matched, not just 4 static strings.

Answer (score 2):

From your examples, I guess you are trying to check if there is only one `'` in the String.

The regex can be `^[^']*'[^']*$`, that with the `matches` method can be reduced to `[^']*'[^']*`:

- `[^']*`: Everything that is not `'`
- `'`: A `'`
- `[^']*`: Everything that is not `'`

---

```
String[] a = {
    "' or abc",
    "X' or abc",
    "Good X' or abc",
    "Good 'X' or abc"
};

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^']*'[^']*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a[i]);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

However, you don't need a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` for that purpose, just use

```
yourString.matches("[^']*'[^']*");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in the description, I have to put ".*" at both begin and end of the regex. If I do like that for your regex, the regex would be ".*([^']*'[^']*).*", and the forth one returns true.

Comment: @qiuzmjq Can I ask you why do you have to put `.*` at the begin and at the end of the regex? If you want to explain, maybe we can find a better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This regex, which employs a negative look ahead, passes your tests:

```
if (str.matches("^(?!(.*?'){2}).*"))
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/JvDwKfzlGo).